# CRS Austrian Lambert/WGS84

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am totally new to Qgis (or GIS in total):
My problem is to get two layers in same CRS to do an intersection and further analysis described in the blog of underdark (Groupstat tutorial).

My is the CORINE-AT clip from here: http://www.umweltbundesamt.at/umweltsituation/umweltinfo/opendata/oed_landbedeckung/?cgiproxy_url=http%3A%2F%2Fhttpapp5.umweltbundesamt.at%2Fdata%2Fdataset.jsf%3Bjsessionid%3D2E72E8BB3EB1C39EEBDC124E516B445C%3Fid%3D1

and the country data from DIVA-GIS: http://gadm.org/data/shp/AUT_adm.zip

As far as I could see the CORINE data is in Austrian Lambert and the country data is in WGS84.

I tried to change the CRS via right click to layer, via vector-> define actual projection, change the WGS84 to Austrian Lambert and then save the shape file...

There were always two outcomes: 
Error in CRS:... or

The layer did not lay on each other (country data is flattened).

However the result when doing the intersecting (or clipping, or anything else) is an empty attribute table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use "define actual projection". Just make sure the country data has WGS84 specified in layer properties CRS definition. Then use "Save as ..." and select Austria Lambert as target CRS.